# RestController Returning 404 (Spring Boot 2.3.7)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have written a Spring Boot application with RestContoller. But when I hit the URL in a browser, I get a 404 error. But i am not sure what I am doing wrong. Everything seems to be all correct. My controller class looks like this:

```
package com.gtt.wcas.device.root;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class DeviceConnectionController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceConnectionController.class.getName());

    .
    .
    .
    // Lots of variables
    .
    .
    .


    @RequestMapping(value = "/deviceConnection", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> deviceConnection(@RequestParam(value = "verify", defaultValue = "false") String verify) {

        .
        .
        //Method body.... lots of code...
        .
        .

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> error () {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }


    .
    .
    .
    // Lots of other helper methods.
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My main class is like this:

```
package com.gtt.wcas.device.root;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gtt.wcas.device.details")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = "com.gtt.wcas.device.configuration")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.gtt.wcas.device.db.jpa")
public class wcasDeviceConnectionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(wcasDeviceConnectionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My application properties are:

```
#datasource configurations
spring.datasource.url=MY DB URL
spring.datasource.username=MY DB USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=MY DB PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

# DDL generation
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

logging.level.ch.qos.logback==DEBUG
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
debug=true
```

And when I enter `http://localhost:8080/deviceConnection?verify=true` on the browser, I see this in the logs:

```
2022-06-16 19:00:00.078 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/deviceConnection?verify=true", parameters={masked}
2022-06-16 19:00:00.079 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-06-16 19:00:00.082 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-06-16 19:00:00.082 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-06-16 19:00:00.082 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?verify=true", parameters={masked}
2022-06-16 19:00:00.083 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-06-16 19:00:00.096 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-06-16 19:00:00.097 DEBUG 19444 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `com.gtt.wcas.device.root` in `@ComponentScan` ? and check , I've observed this issue with Spring boot , sometimes ,it does not identify endpoints if your Controller is in different package and not explicitly Scanned. Also, you don't need `@ResponseBody` since `@RestController` already has that definition!

Comment: @Harsh Dang it! That was a trivial problem. Adding to the `ComponentScan` fixed the problem. Can you please make it the answer. I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add `com.gtt.wcas.device.root` in `@ComponentScan` ? and check ,

I've observed this issue with Spring boot , sometimes ,it does not identify endpoints if your Controller is in different package (other than source package) and not explicitly Scanned.

Also, you don't need `@ResponseBody` on top of method definitions since `@RestController` already has that definition!

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is in package `com.gtt.wcas.device.root` but you setup `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gtt.wcas.device.details")`.

You controller is never picked up by Spring. Either move it to another package or change your component scan.